# Drive REST API no longer returning user name for deleted comments?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

We've been using the Google Drive REST v3 API to retrieve comments with the `includeDeleted` option.

Until sometime within just the last few days this returned the user name of the person who made the deleted comment, though the content itself was no longer available.

Now we're not getting the user name, either. Has anyone else experienced this?

API parameters:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{MyFileId}/comments?includeDeleted=true&pageSize=100&fields=comments
```

Output for two deleted comments containing no user information:

```
{
   "kind": "drive#comment",
   "id": "AAAAC8EryOw",
   "createdTime": "2019-05-08T14:47:46.931Z",
   "modifiedTime": "2019-05-08T14:48:01.276Z",
   "deleted": true,
   "replies": []
  },

{
   "kind": "drive#comment",
   "id": "AAAAC4otGzE",
   "createdTime": "2019-05-06T09:33:32.862Z",
   "modifiedTime": "2019-05-08T14:37:48.699Z",
   "deleted": true,
   "replies": []
},
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. We used v2 for a long time, and my fingers were used to typing that...

Comment: what profile permissions did the users grant to your app?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be having an issue with the [partial response](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/performance#partial-response) of the Google Drive api v3. Try setting fields = *

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{MyFileId}/comments?includeDeleted=true&pageSize=100&fields=*
```

If that doesnt work i suspect you will need to do a [comment.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/comments/get) which will allow you to see the full comment response for each comment.

```
{
  "kind": "drive#comment",
  "id": string,
  "createdTime": datetime,
  "modifiedTime": datetime,
  "author": {
    "kind": "drive#user",
    "displayName": string,
    "photoLink": string,
    "me": boolean,
    "permissionId": string,
    "emailAddress": string
  },
  "htmlContent": string,
  "content": string,
  "deleted": boolean,
  "resolved": boolean,
  "quotedFileContent": {
    "mimeType": string,
    "value": string
  },
  "anchor": string,
  "replies": [
    replies Resource
  ]
}
```